# Opening modal with hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, hashtag

I want to open a modal with hash (example: www.example.com/#example.) This is my code below but the modal not showing. Thanks for your answer and I appreciate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup').click(openModalPopupClick);

          function openModalPopup(){
            var hashText = window.location.hash.substr();
            if (hashText){
              $('#'+hashText).modal('show');
            }
          }

          function openModalPopupClick(){
            var hashText = $(this).attr('href');
            if (hashText){
              $(hashText).modal('show');
            }
          }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#regis-new-company" class="popup" role="button">click</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="regis-new-company" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"></div>
       <div class="modal-body"></div>
       <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I updated your question with `bootstrap` cdn, now it's look like working, little unclear what's your problem, `#regis-new-company` modal works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hashText**  allready have # so `$('#'+hashText).modal('show');` should be `$(hashText).modal('show');` and call `openModalPopupClick` function on ready. i have update your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup').click(openModalPopupClick);

      function openModalPopup(){
        var hashText = window.location.hash.substr();
        if (hashText){
          $(hashText).modal('show');
        }
      }

      openModalPopup();

      function openModalPopupClick(){
        var hashText = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hashText){
          $(hashText).modal('show');
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: hey @zeeshan Anjum thank you very much, your code worked! but now i have another problem with my collapse. thats function openModalPopup(); conflict with my collapse accordion in same page. When I enter another hastag url in that page for collapse function, the openModalPopup(); always call so the page show the half gray popup background.

Comment: if(location.hash != null && location.hash != ""){
        $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
        $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
    } 
 
 //popup link
 $('.popup').click(openModalPopupClick);

      function openModalPopup(){
        var hashText = window.location.hash.substr();
        if (hashText){
          $(hashText).modal('show');
        }
      }

      openModalPopup();

      function openModalPopupClick(){
        var hashText = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hashText){
          $(hashText).modal('show');
        }
      }

Comment: you can add condition when openModalPopup function should call. like 
`if(hashText  == "#open-modal")openModalPopup();`

Comment: hello @zeeshan anjum can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662730/conflict-function-modal-and-collapse-when-i-using-hashtext